# test transaction propagation with service and DAO

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, transactions, dao

I have a service method of the service class, which is a Spring bean, that looks like

```
@Transactional
public void doThis() {
    dao.d1();
    dao.d2();
}
```

and in my DAO class, which extends Spring's NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport. I have it set up as

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public void d1(){...}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public void d2(){...}
```

and the configuration looks like

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Now my question is, how can I integration test it in Spring context? I have tested my DAO with AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests and an embedded database. how will I test the chain of service and DAO now so if dao throws a RuntimeException, I can see the whole transaction is rolled back?

Hope I explain it well. Any hints/suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Without instrumenting your code for testing this transactional case, it may be hard to turn this into a simple repeatable JUnit test.

With a little extra code in the dao, you could have your d2 method look for something to force it to throw a test RuntimeException.  Perhaps a ThreadLocal flag could be used to indicate your want your code to fail.

Alternatively, you could just make d2() fail every time until you have become comfortable that the transactional semantics are being applied correctly.

Comment: thank you for your comment, Marc. I am wondering if I can use a DAO mock that throws excetpion in d1 method first, then test if the the transaction in the caller at service layer is rolled back; then change the mock to let it throw exception in d2, and see if the transaction is rolled back. That is my idealistic case

Comment: I like using a DAO mock - but I'm not sure what your first test will validate.  If d1() aborts, d2() never gets called, right?  Having d2() abort should rollback d1()'s changes though. The other thought I have is in regards to where you will verify the rollback.  It is likely that your object state will be insufficient to check - perhaps better to verify the underlying datastore?

Comment: Yes Marc. I want to test if d2 fails, d1 is rolled back and I am checking that using the data stored in the embedded datastore

Answer (score 0):

I actually just tested it with AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests and embedded database, as I would test my DAO. Just add service layer to the story and a DAO stub that would throw RuntimeException in the method triggered in the downstream. It worked fine. The transaction rollback is verified